# What is the correct way to check for attachEvent() availability?

Tags: javascript

I have seen these 3:

```
if(window.attacheEvent)

if(document.attachEvent)

if(element.attachEvent)
```

**Note:**

- element is readily available.
- no libraries please

**Applied with the Fascade Pattern per Answer**

```
$NS.addEventL = (function determineEventBinding(){
    if(window.attachEvent){
        return function attachEvent(element, type, callNow){
            element.attachEvent('on' + type, callNow);
        }
    }
    else {
        return function addEventListener(element, type, callNow){
            element.addEventListener(type, callNow);
        }
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all 'correct' in that they will produce the same results (assuming `element` is a DOM node). The advantage with `window` and `document` is that you will not have to create or find an element to test functionality, meaning you can perform your test more efficiently.

You say `element` is readily available: this suggests you are writing a plugin / library / module which creates elements and binds events to them. I would say, fork your events separately:

Whereas you may have code like this:

```
function createButton(){
    // Create element
    var button = document.createElement('input');

    // Bind event
    if(button.attachEvent){
        button.attachEvent('onclick', actionTrigger);
    }
    else {
        button.addEventListener('click', actionTrigger, false);
    }

    return button;
}
```

You may be better off writing your own wrapper function, as such:

```
var bindEvent = (function determineEventBinding(){
    if(window.attachEvent){
        return function attachEvent(element, hook, func){
            element.attachEvent('on' + hook, func);
        }
    }
    else {
        return function addEventListener(element, hook, func){
            element.addEventListener(hook, func, false);
        }
    }
}());
```

...And then forget all about the headache, using your wrapper when writing functional code:

```
function createButton(){
    // Create element
    var button = document.createElement('input');

    // Bind event
    bindEvent(button, 'click', actionTrigger);

    return button;
}
```

The advantages are manifold:

1. The code to determine the method only needs to run once
2. That code can run as soon as script execution starts — staying out of the way of performance congestion hotspots like DOM ready, or user CTA
3. You can forget all about browser disparities while writing your esoteric functional code, and your code will read and perform better as a result
4. If you need to support new browser disparities, or fix existing ones, you can edit the code in once place rather than tracing each time you bind an event

Comment: "They should all point to the same place in the code native to the browser" — no, the code (I assume typos, with an intent of `(window || document || element).attachEvent`) will return the first object out of `window`, `document` and `element` that returns truthy (`window`), and sees if _it_ has an `attachEvent` property. Unless I misunderstand you and you're asking which, out of the 3, is quicker to query? I would say they're all just as fast.

Comment: Ah, right — thought it was a bit odd you were doing bitwise or on DOM elements. The short answer is that there is no significant performance penalty on grabbing any of these.

Comment: `attachEvent` would be prototyped in at some nebulous higher point, yes. The only expense factor would come from crawling scope to retrieve the object on which to look for the method…

Comment: @pure_code slight mistake in your copy of my code: `determineEventBinding` should not have argument labels. The function is [immediately invoked](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) by virtue of having parentheses immediately afterwards (last line of code block: `}())`). Anything within those parentheses is immediately passed in as arguments (in this case, nothing). The function runs immediately and the output (one of the 2 `return`s) is assigned to `addEventL`.